# A script to preload images and then fire a callback when they are?

Tags: javascript, image

Is there any way I could load an image via javascript and then have a callback fire when it is finished?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){ alert('loaded'); };
img.src = '/some/image.jpg';
```

**UPDATE**

sure you can set the background-image of an element with this. Use the onload event to do whatever you like!

```
// change background to image - only after image completely loaded
function setBackroundImage(node, imageUrl) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    node.style.backgroundImage = imageUrl;
  }
  img.src = imageUrl;
}
```

setBackroundImage(document.getElementById('foobar'), '/some/image.jpg');

Comment: Ok cool, more simple then I thought. Can I pass a reference to it into that function? Say if I wanted to set it as a background via css?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to handle image load:

```
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'
$(img).load(function(){ alert('Image loaded')})
$('#container').append(img)
```